Google System updates on devices enrolled using Android Enterprise not working(EMM)
Enterprise application looking for the Android system update automatically, (When new android version is available should download and install)
    private val dpm: DevicePolicyManager by lazy {
        context.getSystemService(DevicePolicyManager::class.java)
    }

    private val adminComponentName: ComponentName by lazy {
        ComponentName(context.applicationContext, AdminReceiver::class.java)
    }

// Updating the system policy
    val updatePolicy = SystemUpdatePolicy.createAutomaticInstallPolicy()
    dpm.setSystemUpdatePolicy(adminComponentName, updatePolicy)

Note: System update is downloading but not installing from the enterprise user. text
Device policy setup for the system update and installation but did not install the update. Expecting to download and auto install without any confirmation. Google System updates
